# Scanner class and an Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been struggling with the scanner class. I just can't seem to rap my head around it's methods. I'm trying to run set of code which seems right to me. I've tried a few tweaks but still nothing. Any hints of why i am receiving this error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException  at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)  at
>   PolynomialTest.main(PolynomialTest.java:18)"

```
public class PolynomialTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

Scanner fileData = new Scanner(new File("operations.txt"));
Polynomial math = new Polynomial();
int coeff = fileData.nextInt();
int expo = fileData.nextInt();

while (fileData.hasNext()) {

    Scanner nextTerm = new Scanner(fileData.nextLine());

    if (nextTerm.next().equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {

        math.insert(coeff, expo);
        System.out.println("The term (" + coeff + ", " + expo
                + ") has been added to the list in its proper place");
        System.out.println("The list is now: " + math.toString());

    } else if (nextTerm.next().equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {

        math.delete(coeff, expo);
        System.out.println("The following term has been removed ("
                + coeff + ", " + expo + ")");
        System.out.println("The list is now: " + math.toString());

    } else if (nextTerm.next().equalsIgnoreCase("reverse")) {

        math.reverse();
        System.out
                .println("The list was reversed in order and the list is now: "
                        + math.toString());

    } else if (nextTerm.next().equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {

        System.out.println("The product of the polynomial is: "
                + math.product());

    } else {

        System.out.println("Not a recognized input method");

    }
    nextTerm.close();
}
PrintWriter save = new PrintWriter("operations.txt");
save.close();
fileData.close();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is number of issue at your code. Never called `nextLine()` after `while(hasNext())`. Your `while` loop should be

```
while (fileData.hasNextLine()) {
   Scanner nextTerm = new Scanner(fileData.nextLine());
```

You called `nextTerm.next()` at every `if-else` statement. You should assign a `String` variable named operation.

```
   String operation=nextTerm.next();

   if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {
      ....
   } else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
    ..........
   } 
   ...
   else if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {
     .....
   }
```

Comment: Is hasNextLine() a proper scanner method? I haven't tried the code yet i am just asking because we were taught hasNext() returns true if there is another non whitespace string and false if there isn't. Are they the samething?

Comment: @Brwski, hasNext() traverses space by space, whereas hasNextLine() with line by line. As you used nextLine() after while loop, so you should use hasNextLine().

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe it has something to do with my coeff and expo variables. When i try to echoprint using those variables, would that be a problem? Is there another way to echo print what was added or deleted without using those variables?

Answer (score 1):

InputMismatchException is Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

```
int coeff = fileData.nextInt();
int expo = fileData.nextInt();
```

try change above to as below.(If you have first 2 integer inputs in 2 separate lines, otherwise try parsing them after read them using `fileData.nextLine().split(" ")` )

```
int coeff  = Integer.parseInt(fileData.nextLine());
int expo = Integer.parseInt(fileData.nextLine());
```

if 2 integers in the same line

```
    String s[] = fileData.nextLine().split(" ");
    int coeff   = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
    int expo  = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);
```

good if you can post your `Polynomial` class also...